# How to get a handle of a StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf

I use the following statement in the 'code-behind' to get a handle of a StackPanel:

```
HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(panelName) as HwndSource;
Int32 studioHandle = (Int32)source.Handle;
```

but I get run-time exception that 'object reference is not set to an instance....' and 'source' is null.

This is how I declare the StackPanel in XAML:

```
 <StackPanel Name ="panelName" Grid.Row="18" Grid.Column="65" Grid.ColumnSpan="101" Grid.RowSpan="57" Background="Black"/>
```

Comment: WPF is not using GDI for the presentation, hence it will always be `null`.

Comment: Child controls in WPF, like StackPanel, don't have a dedicated window handle, they paint themselves on top of a window that does.  The Window class has one.  You could perhaps use a WindowsFormsHost to wrap a winforms panel.

Answer (score 0):

The way to obtain the Handle of a window in WPF is to use a WindowInteropHelper: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper